# Error when trying to include GLEW and SDL_opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, kinect, glew

I am going through a tutorial for some kinect code and I cant seem to get the includes to work. When I include the code below I get the error:

Error   1   error C2371: 'PFNGLFRAGMENTLIGHTFVSGIXPROC' : redefinition; different basic types

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <SDL\SDL.h>
#include <SDL\SDL_opengl.h>
#include <Kinect\Kinect.h>
```

I have been told to use #define NO_SDL_GLEXT but when I include that I get 16 new errors.

```
#define NO_SDL_GLEXT
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <SDL\SDL.h>
#include <SDL\SDL_opengl.h>
#include <Kinect\Kinect.h>
```

- Error    8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl drawKinectData(void)" (?drawKinectData@@YAXXZ)
- Error    9   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function _SDL_main
- Error    10  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearDepth@8 referenced in function _SDL_main
- Error    23  error LNK1120: 15 unresolved externals

Is there any way I can get some help on this? If I haven't provided enough information or you need more clarity let me know. Thanks! :)

Edit 1: I was told that this is a duplicate and shown a document talking about how to include libraries into the project. I do not believe or understand if that is the issue because I have already configured the project in visual studios as shown in these links:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGca2.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS936.jpg

Comment: The errors mean you need to *link* libraries together.  Header files only instruct the compiler about how to call the functions.

Comment: I have the .dll files in the same folder as the .exe and I have the libraries set in the linker: SDL.lib;SDLmain.lib;glew32.lib;Kinect20.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies). Is this what you meant?